# Power bank charging using a solar panel

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, dc-dc-converter, lithium-ion, solar-charge-controller

I'm trying to charge a power bank of 5V, 5000mAh, using a solar panel 6V, 14W.

I have made the connection from the solar panel to a DC-DC convertor (specification: 3-37V, 3A) which steps down to a fixed voltage of 5V. From there, I fed the output of the DC-DC converter to the power bank input, which requires an input voltage of 5V.

But I can't see any charging indication and charging is not taking place. I'm not able to find why it isn't able to charge the power bank. What is my mistake?

[image: PCB of power bank]

Comment: I guess I'd take the 'divide and conquer' approach. For instance, does your power bank work when plugged into a standard USB port or power plug? Are you trying to charge and power a device at the same time (probably won't give good results)? What does the output of your DC-DC convertor look like (voltage, etc.) when powered by a 6V supply? Are you getting 6V out of your panel (solar panels can vary quite a bit from their labeled rating, depending on shade, sun intensity, etc).

Comment: Yes the power bank,work when connected to a standard USB port,

Comment: No im not charging and drawing the power from the power bank at the same time. The outfit of the Dc-Dc convertor i have set it at files 5V.  Yes the solar panel is adequately having enough voltage innfact its Voc is greater than 5V.

Comment: @Shiv - There *sees* to be a logical error / contradiction in your question, which makes it difficult to understand your story. You said: "*I can't see any Charging indication and charging is taking place*". That *seems* to be saying "*I can't see any Charging indication*" - so the charger indicates charging **is not** happening, but "*charging is taking place*" so somehow (you don't explain how) you know that charging **is** happening. Perhaps you meant "*I can't see any Charging indication and charging is not taking place*"?

Comment: Do you have a multimeter? (a) If so, what voltages did you measure, when you were *trying* to charge the power bank (i.e. with the solar panel being "illuminated") at point (i) the output of the solar panel (which is also the input of the DC-DC converter), and point (ii) the output of the DC-DC converter (which is also the input to the USB power bank)? (b) Then disconnect the USB power bank, and measure the voltages at the two points (i) and (ii) like before. What did you measure? (c) Then also disconnect the DC-DC converter (so there is only the solar panel). What is the voltage at point (i)?

Comment: Yes I can say that the charging is not taking place,instead it had stopped working, i mean to say when I tried to charge it with a standard power supply again after reis to charging with the solar panels and dc dc convertor.

Comment: Ive measured 1)The solar panel Voc which is about 10-11v approx,2)The output of the Dc Dc convertor I've set at 5V. I did not measure the remaining voltages at the points mentioned, but if at all I want to measure it again, im fearing that the power bank may not work again. Initially it did not work soon i tried to charge using solar panel and dc dc convertor, what I've did was break open the power bank, and de-solder the batteries and soldered it agian and it resumed to start working.

Comment: @Shiv - I cannot help you with diagnosing your problem, unless you supply all of the 5 voltage measurements which I listed. The voltages you have listed are not enough. || I realise that English isn't your first language, and unfortunately I don't understand most of your last comment. || However you have said that you "*de-solder the batteries and soldered it agian and it resumed to start working*" so *if* I understand you correctly, you have solved your own problem, and so this question is now *not* required. Is that correct?

Comment: The contradiction for Voc=10~11V is that your DC-DC does not maintain 72%~82% If Voc=Vmpt therefore will fail from impedance transformer relationship most of the time. All of the time Zpmt must equal Voc/Isc

Comment: Sorry for my english, yes it is not my first language i agree,But what I want to ask is can i charge the power bank with the above said technique, or shall I add some circuitry into it. And what ever i was doing is proper?

Comment: @Shiv - Although I could *guess* at an answer, I cannot be confident of diagnosing your problem, unless you supply all of the 5 voltage measurements which I listed. Therefore I will stop here. (As you can see, I have updated your question, to try to improve readability and to fix the logical error which we discussed.) Good luck!

Comment: Hope i will find out the exact reason why it can't able to charge through the above said method.

Comment: If 1) you can charge your power bank with standard 5V power supply and 2) your DC-DC outputs 5V with sufficient current under load then you should be able to charge your power bank without any additional circuitry. However you give different information to the two points above. And confusing information on other points, e.g. "solar panel 6V" and "solar panel Voc which is about 10-11v". Do you have 2 panels in series?

Comment: No the solar panels aren't in series.

Comment: Then you need to provide more details as others pointed out, because what you have said already is awfully confusing and contradictory.

Comment: @TonyStewartolderthandirt What is Vmpt?  Zpmt?  And where do you see a transformer?

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely a 6V, 14W solar panel has sufficient power to charge your power bank.

14 W is a maximum under ideal conditions and very likely an exaggeration by the vendor. A solar panel will have an IV curve.  6V is a nominal voltage and actual V<sub>oc</sub> will vary widely depending on irradiance and load.

You need to use a shunt resistor to also measure the solar panel's current while measuring the output voltage.

You do not say how you know whether the battery pack is being charged or not.

With your solar panel, *if* it has sufficient power to charge at all, it may take days of bright sunshine to charge the battery pack.  Do not assume the solar panel is providing 14 watts of power, measure it.

A solar source is typically connected to an MPPT rather than a DC-DC converter.

A solar panel is used for practical purposes only where there is no utility power available.  It takes many (e.g. 20) years of use to recoup the cost in electricity savings if ever.  The cost analysis is not simply electricity cost ÷ (panel watts x time). Usually the cost of the batteries that need to be replaced every few years prohibits any cost savings.